# ¿Por qué una pregunta en espera es cerrada si el usuario que la formuló la ha corregido?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta

La vez pasada realicé [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75044/13558) y los moderadores la pusieron en espera, ya que dicha pregunta era muy amplia. En la leyenda inferior aconsejaba limitarla a un tema específico, lo hice, pero después de dos días se cerró la pregunta.

¿Por qué pasó eso si se cumplió con lo sugerido?

Comment: Además de la respuesta de que se votó por mantener cerrada, me gustaría comentar que el sitio no es un reemplazo de Google. Si la pregunta busca determinar diferencias en la eficiencia/el funcionamiento de los diferentes tipos de índices, esperaría ver un esfuerzo de investigación en la pregunta que liste esos índices, explique qué información se encontró y consulte sobre las dudas específicas luego de eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si puedes ver el [timeline de tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/75044/timeline), pero si no puedes, te voy a poner una captura aquí (cortada):

[image: Linea del tiempo de la pregunta enlazada]

La cosa es que se puso la pregunta en espera e hiciste las actualizaciones en la misma como se pedía. Entonces la pregunta pasó a la cola de reapertura, pero se votó mantenerla cerrada y por eso se cerró a pesar de hacer los cambios.

Tal y como está ahora mismo la pregunta, creo que sigue siendo un poco amplia y por eso se votó el mantenerla cerrada. Quizás si la pregunta se concretara más en MySQL (¿Qué tipos de índices puedo usar en MySQL?), o si pusieras la estructura de una tabla o una SELECT como ejemplo (¿Qué tipo de índices puedo usar en MySQL en tal o cual columna?) tendría mejor aceptación.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro Montoro, en definitiva respondiste mi pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Además, creo que hay una confusión en la pregunta. Una pregunta que está cerrada siempre aparece como "en espera" (excepto duplicadas), y [luego de 5 días](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/304899) el texto se cambia por "cerrada". Técnicamente, salvo el texto utilizado, no existe ninguna diferencia entre "en espera" y "cerrada" para lo que concierne a esta pregunta, y normalmente nos podemos referir a ambas como *cerradas*... Una pregunta *cerrada* puede ser editada y reabierta en cualquier momento (sea día 1 o 5+).